# C++ ERROR: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee

Tags: c++

I get this error **" 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee"** in *c++* program.

My code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public: 
string name; 
int age;
int phone;
int salary;
};
int main()
{

Employee emp1;

ofstream f1;

f1.open("qwe.txt",ios::binary|ios::app);

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)

{
    cout<<"enter name:\t";
    cin>>emp1.name;
    cout<<"enter age:\t";
    cin>>emp1.age;
    cout<<"enter phone:\t";
    cin>>emp1.phone;
    cout<<"enter salary:\t";
    cin>>emp1.salary;
    cout<<"\n";
    f1.write((char *)(&emp1),sizeof(Employee));
}

f1.close();

Employee emp2;
ifstream f2;
f2.open("qwe.txt",ios::binary|ios::in);
while(f2)
{
    f2.read((char *)(&emp2),sizeof(Employee));
    if(f2.eof())
    {
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<emp2.name;
        cout<<"\n"<<emp2.age;
        cout<<"\n"<<emp2.phone;
        cout<<"\n"<<emp2.salary<<"\n";  
    }
}
f2.close();

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is in `while(f2)`. But I am not sure. This line  `f2.read((char *)(&emp2),sizeof(Employee))` may create problem. But I need this line.

Comment: `ifstream::read` has a prototype, what is a contract. You are violating this contract, take the cast as evidence. Why do you expect something different than undefined behavior if you violate the contract?

Answer (score 2):

You could not read/write structures with a complex types, like `std::string` that way. They have an internal structure which is implementation specific. Directly overriding its memory is a surest way to shoot yourself in the foot. Use `>>`/`<<` operators instead:

```
f1 << emp1.name;
f1 << emp1.age;
//...
f2 >> emp2.name;
f2 >> emp2.age;
```

Answer (score 1):

The internal representation of a class is implementation defined. Additionally the `string` member can hold the data in the member directly or in an additional heap object depending of the number of charaters.

That's why you need a serialization of instances of your class. The serialize function will take serialization target like `ofstream` an writes a represenation of the data. The deserialization function will take a serialization source like `ifstream` and reads the reprensentation to the members.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a low level API as used in your code(read/write) check out:

Be careful, the following line can break your data, I was changed this to avoid the previous valued writed by you.

```
f1.open("qwe.txt", ios::binary | ios::trunc);
```

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
 public:
  string name;
  int age;
  int phone;
  int salary;
};
int main() {
  Employee emp1;

  ofstream f1;

  f1.open("qwe.txt", ios::binary | ios::trunc);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)

  {
    cout << "enter name:\t";
    cin >> emp1.name;
    cout << "enter age:\t";
    cin >> emp1.age;
    cout << "enter phone:\t";
    cin >> emp1.phone;
    cout << "enter salary:\t";
    cin >> emp1.salary;
    cout << "\n";

    size_t lenght = emp1.name.size();
    char lenghtval[sizeof(lenght)];
    std::memcpy(&lenghtval, &lenght, sizeof(lenght));
    f1.write(lenghtval, sizeof(lenght));
    const char *name = emp1.name.c_str();
    f1.write(name, static_cast<int>(lenght));
    int val = emp1.age;
    char towrite[sizeof(val)];
    std::memcpy(&towrite, &val, sizeof(val));
    f1.write(towrite, sizeof(val));
    val = emp1.phone;
    std::memcpy(&towrite, &val, sizeof(val));
    f1.write(towrite, sizeof(val));
    val = emp1.salary;
    std::memcpy(&towrite, &val, sizeof(val));
    f1.write(towrite, sizeof(val));
  }

  f1.close();

  Employee emp2;
  ifstream f2;
  f2.open("qwe.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
  while (f2) {
    size_t lenght = 0;
    char lenghtval[sizeof(lenght)];
    f2.read(lenghtval, sizeof(lenght));
    std::memcpy(&lenght, lenghtval, sizeof(lenght));
    char name[lenght + 1];
    f2.read(name, static_cast<int>(lenght));
    name[lenght] = '\0';
    emp2.name = name;

    int val = 0;
    char toread[sizeof(val)];
    f2.read(toread, sizeof(val));
    std::memcpy(&val, toread, sizeof(val));
    emp2.age = val;
    f2.read(toread, sizeof(val));
    std::memcpy(&val, toread, sizeof(val));
    emp2.phone = val;
    f2.read(toread, sizeof(val));
    std::memcpy(&val, toread, sizeof(val));
    emp2.salary = val;

    if (f2.eof()) {
      break;
    }
    cout << "\n" << emp2.name << std::endl;
    cout << "\n" << emp2.age;
    cout << "\n" << emp2.phone;
    cout << "\n" << emp2.salary << "\n";
  }
  f2.close();

  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```